# Test apps on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

A new function in Xcode 7 is that I can test my apps on iOS devices without a paid developer account.
It works fine on my iPad air, but when I try it out with my iPhone 5s I'll always get some kind error message.

I have tried with multiple Apple-ID's, and i have restored my iPhone (from a backup)
I have tried with one of my friend's iPad to, and it worked fine.

I hope some of you can help me.

**Update**

The error message Xcode gives when trying to install an app on the iPhone.

[image: The error message]

Comment: "some kind of error message."? You will need some kind of fix then.

Comment: What version of iOS is running on the iPhone 5S?

Comment: I'am running iOS 9.1, and Xcode 7.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was relating to the name of the device, I solved it by changing the device name from an unsupported, blank(￼), Unicode character.